# Exporting high-resolution world map image from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, print-composer

I'm trying to get some (very) large world map images (think 10k x 10k pixels etc), but can't seem to do it with QGIS.

Manually adding smaller images to a larger one works (albeit slowly) for continental landmasses, but not for various mid-ocean islands etc, as I've no reference points handy.

The "Save as image" command only saves what's on-screen at the moment, the "Print Composer" system ditto.

Ideally, I'd hit a button & QGIS would export the entire project to a single giant .tiff image, or perhaps a series of tiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for print composer. Increase the page size and resolution. Add the map and if you want to create a map of the whole world, make sure you zoom to full extent. Then save as image. If the size is not big enough, increase the paper size further. A0 with 300dpi should easily be possible if you have enough RAM.

Answer (score 1):

If you have georeferenced images, you can use `Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Build Virtual Raster` or `Merge` to make a single raster from them.

The first one does not even create large files. If you have finished adding images, you can still export to geotiff.

Comment: note that when you export to geotif, you will need the bigtif option as you'll probably exceed 4Gb. This is more convenient to do with gdal. but the vrt is the best solution